# Excel Formula for Entering a New Cell Numerical Value When Another Cell Numerical Value is Some Number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have one cell that has an INDEX value (e.g. 23.1).  There is another cell (COURSE HANDICAP) that takes this INDEX value and rounds the index using the following: =IF(E3-INT(E3)<0.5,ROUNDDOWN(E3,0),ROUNDUP(E3,0)).  When rounded, it gives me golfer's course handicap (e.g. 25 strokes).

Now I want to take the INDEX value (25) and distribute the golfer's strokes to the handicap holes.  For example, handicap holes #1 thru #18 are handicapped according to difficulty as 1, 15, 7, 17, 3, 9, 5, 13, 11, 8, 12, 4, 6, 16, 14, 2, 10, and 18, respectively.

results with 18 handicap

```
HOLE | DIFFICULTY | HDCP
01   | 01         | 1
02   | 15         | 1
03   | 07         | 1
04   | 17         | 1
05   | 03         | 1
06   | 09         | 1
07   | 05         | 1
08   | 13         | 1
09   | 11         | 1
10   | 08         | 1
11   | 12         | 1
12   | 04         | 1
13   | 06         | 1
14   | 16         | 1
15   | 14         | 1
16   | 02         | 1
17   | 10         | 1
18   | 18         | 1
```

If a player has a course handicap of 18 strokes, then that player gets 1 stroke per hole, distributed evenly to each of the 18 holes.  However if the player's handicap is 25, he gets the follow stroke distribution:

1. Handicap Hole #1 = 2 strokes
2. Handicap hole #2 = 2 strokes
3. Handicap hole #3 = 2 strokes
4. Handicap hole #4 = 2 strokes
5. Handicap hole #5 = 2 strokes
6. Handicap hole #6 = 2 strokes
7. Handicap hole #7 = 2 strokes
8. Handicap hole #8 = 1 stroke
9. Handicap hole #9 = 1 stroke
10. Handicap hole #10 = 1 stroke
11. Handicap hole #11 = 1 stroke
12. Handicap hole #12 = 1 stroke
13. Handicap hole #13 = 1 stroke
14. Handicap hole #14 = 1 stroke
15. Handicap hole #15 = 1 stroke
16. Handicap hole #16 = 1 stroke
17. Handicap hole #17 = 1 stroke
18. Handicap hole #18 = 1 stroke

Total Strokes = 25

Note that handicap hole #1 is the most difficult and therefore gets 2 strokes, etc.  As the individual COURSE HANDICAP value changes (in this case, 18 or 25), so do the number of strokes allotted per handicap hole.

I want to be able to take the value in the COURSE HANDICAP cell (e.g. 25) and distribute the handicap strokes to the proper handicap holes.  Since the players' course handicaps will vary, so will the strokes allotted per handicap hole.

I am also looking for a reliable iOS app builder.

Comment: Why not one for android?

Comment: 1) your description of the problem is a little confusing because there is also a function in excel called INDEX.  I am assuming when you describe INDEX in your description it is not the same thing. 2) you list of difficulty **rating** is 1,2,3... are high difficulty, and 16 17 18 low levels of difficulty?  If that is true, you basically want to list holes 1-18 in say column A, put their corresponding difficulty rating in column B, then sort by column B, Then start filling in column C with 1 stroke at a time until you run out of strokes.  Column C would then be the Handicap per hole.

Comment: I edited your question to show a table of my interpretation of what you are talking about.  if it is wrong delete it.  If its right, copy it and adjust the stroke count for how you want it to read for a 25 stroke count.  right now what you have said in your example does not make much sense as hole 4 which should be relatively easy is getting a 2 stroke handicap in your example.

Comment: Do you want some help with code you're writing or do you want someone to write it all for you?

Answer (score 0):

Brings back memories of doing this in FORTRAN for our golf league.

Two parts:
First, how many times does 18 go into the course handicap,
Second, what is the remainder of the course handicap modulo 18

For holes numbered greater than the remainder, stick in the first number, the easy holes.
For holes numbered less than or equal to the remainder, stick in the first number plus 1, the hard holes.

This formula is similar to what you want to do, including plus handicaps like -4.
B$1 is where the handicap is stored. A2 is the difficulty rating for a particular hole.
=IF(A2>MOD(B$1,18),FLOOR(B$1/18),FLOOR(B$1/18)+1)